# AngularJS multiple forms - how to submit forms by name?

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap accordion with a form in each Accordion. How can I submit the form by the id or name of the form? In essence I have an click event bound to the accordion and I would like to pass the name of the form as a parameter somehow and then submit it?

thanks

http://plnkr.co/edit/GMJ8fTWqSw2STnG4V2Ri?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in the form's name or id, you should pass in the object that the form is bound to, or just dynamically pull it from the controller's `$scope`.

In angular it is considered bad form to have anything DOM related in your controller. By using the DOM in a controller it dramatically reduces the test-ability of the controller which is one of the key pillars that angular is built upon.

example:

```
<form ng-submit="handleSubmit(formData)">
    <input ng-model="formData.field1"/>
    <input ng-model="formData.field2"/>
</form>
```

Based upon your plnkr example to call the function defined in your form's rcSubmit attribute do this:

```
formElement.bind('submit', function () {
    $parse(attributes.rcSubmit)();
});
```

The [documentation for $parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24parse) states `Converts Angular expression into a function` which is exactly what you need in this case.

Comment: I get that part. I guess that part I'm wanting to do is call the submit function programmatically? If I wanted to submit the forms individually from the directive. What's the best way to do this ? I'm only submitting one form at a time.

Comment: @user686483 I updated my answer to call the submit function from your directive

Comment: Thanks @Brocco, if i need to call that inside another controller can i inject the directive as a dependencie or  is there something else i need to do?

Comment: That is code for inside your directive, match it up to your submit event handler. When you invoke the parsed method you are calling the method you set in your markup.